# How do I achieve this texture/look?

Tags: texturing

I am trying to make a pill in blender and am trying to achieve optimal realism. I have attached my model thus far as well as what I would like the end result to look like.

Do I add texture in blender or is this more of a Photoshop thing at this point? I want to achieve the crater like indentation on the Tesla/playboy pill. Do I use a PBR texture? I have tried and it looks as if there is a picture of the texture on it instead of the pill taking on the actual texture of the PBR. Any advice would help.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would sculpt some details and imperfections: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndcX3.jpg

Comment: @Blunder - wow that looks so good.. I'm going to do that

Answer (score 1):

You should bevel the edges to make them rounder (here I haven't done it for the letters), and give it a material with a bit of noise for the color and a bit of noise for the bump. Also, lower down the *Specular* value:

[image]

Comment: Woah.. you really did that.. thank you so much this looks really good! You've been great help